# Spring Boot 2 After aspect find success or failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am working on Spring Boot 2 to create a microservice. I have a requirement to create an *After* aspect to execute some piece of code.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FinallyAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(finallyEvent)")
    public void runFinallyMethod(FinallyEvent finallyEvent) {}

    @After("runFinallyMethod(FinallyEvent finallyEvent)")
    public void finallyMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent) throws Throwable { 
       // ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get inside `finallyMethod` whether an exception has occurred or the method returned successfully? I can do it with `@AfterReturning` and `@AfterThrowing` annotation, but if there is a way to check if the method has ended in error or success then I can check it in a single function.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with *After*-advice to access whether the method returned successfully or with an exception. There are alternatives...

#### a) *Around*-advice (not recommended)

What you want can be *manually* implemented with a single method using the *Around*-advice, the most general kind of advice. It is recommended that you use the least powerful advice type that can implement the required behaviour ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introduction-defn)). I do not recommend this approach as it can be error-prone in terms of exception handling if implemented the wrong way. For example, if you put your *success-code* in the try-block, exceptions thrown by this *success-code* are also caught by the same catch-block as is used for the *failure-code*. Also, you need to make sure to re-throw the exception and to return the return value of `joinPoint.proceed()`.

*This is how could do this properly if you wanted to:*

```java
@Around(value = "runFinallyMethod(finallyEvent)", argNames = "joinPoint,finallyEvent")
public Object finallyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent) throws Throwable {
    final Object res;
    try {
        res = joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // code in case of failure
        throw e;
    }
    // code in case of success
    return res;
}
```

#### b) Clean solution with private method

In this case, I suggest to use *AfterReturning*-advice and *AfterThrowing*-advice and then call a private method with a parameter indicating success/error. This is much more readable, does not have the drawbacks of the *Around*-advice but uses a bit more code.

##### A boolean (`success`) is needed

```java
@AfterReturning(value = "runFinallyMethod(finallyEvent)", argNames = "joinPoint,finallyEvent")
public void finallyMethodReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent) throws Throwable {
    finallyMethod(joinPoint, finallyEvent, true);
}

@AfterThrowing(value = "runFinallyMethod(finallyEvent)", argNames = "joinPoint,finallyEvent")
public void finallyMethodThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent) throws Throwable {
    finallyMethod(joinPoint, finallyEvent, false);
}

private void finallyMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent, boolean success) throws Throwable {
    if (success) {
        // code in case of success
    } else {
        // code in case of failure
    }
}
```

##### The `Throwable` is needed

```java
@AfterReturning(value = "runFinallyMethod(finallyEvent)", argNames = "joinPoint,finallyEvent")
public void finallyMethodReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent) throws Throwable {
    finallyMethod(joinPoint, finallyEvent, null);
}


@AfterThrowing(value = "runFinallyMethod(finallyEvent)", throwing = "t", argNames = "joinPoint,finallyEvent,t")
public void finallyMethodThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent, Throwable t) throws Throwable {
    finallyMethod(joinPoint, finallyEvent, t);
}

private void finallyMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinallyEvent finallyEvent, Throwable t) throws Throwable {
    if (t == null) {
        // code in case of success
    } else {
        // code in case of failure
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is good, but I think you want to correct this confusing (and false) statement: _"You need to make sure to re-throw the exception and to return the `ProceedingJoinPoint` instance."_ Probably, you mean to return the return value of `proceed()` rather than the joinpoint instance.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you very much for pointing this out. I just corrected the sentence. Of course I meant the return value of `proceed()` and not the *ProceedingJoinPoint*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to implement this using `@After` as this annotation can only give you the `JoinPoint` in context, which has no information about return values.

If you want to handle everything within the same method I think the only alternative is to implement this using `@Around`, where you can do something before and after a method execution. Your implementation could be:

```
@Around("runFinallyMethod(FinallyEvent finallyEvent)")
public Object finallyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, FinallyEvent finallyEvent) throws Throwable { 
   try {
     Object result = jp.proceed();
     // do nice stuff with result
     return result;
   } catch(Throwable throwable) {
     // do nice stuff with the exception;
     throw throwable;
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not recommend this approach because exceptions thrown by the *success-code* are also caught by the same catch-block as is used for the *failure-code*. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68410708/5024726) explains this and shows how to do it with proper exception handling.

Comment: I agree. He was asking if it can be done in a single method tho, I think there's only this way which isn't ideal.

Comment: If it needs to be one method, the *Around*-aspect is the only way. However, where you place the success/failure-code makes a difference. To have proper exception handling it can be placed as shown in the first part of my answer (variant A). That has equivalent behaviour as the second part of my answer (variant B). The way you have it in your answer will catch an exception thrown in the section *"do nice stuff with result"*, mask the original exception and then execute the section *"do nice stuff with the exception"* in the same way as an exception would have been thrown by `jp.proceed()`.